# Horizontal Recyclerview Scroll

Tags: android

I am trying to implement product comparison. I have 2 recycler view one on top display product and middle one display all summary and specification of product. At a time 2 product are visible on screen.

I am looking when I scrolled the top recycler view horizontally, the bottom recycler view should also scroll to same position as of above to match related product data.

So when top scroll horizontally bottom one should scroll automatically. I am kind of stuck not finding any solution.

Any help would be appreciable.

```
private int overallXScroll = 0;  
    mRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new
    RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            overallXScroll = overallXScroll + dx;
            Log.i("check","overall X  = " + overallXScroll);

        }  });
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: private int overallXScroll = 0;
 //...
 mRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        overallXScroll = overallXScroll + dx;
        Log.i("check","overall X  = " + overallXScroll);

    }
 });

Answer (score 0):

try to work with these. 
We can get visible items form LayoutManagers you can get theses items like these

```
LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
int firstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition = manager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
int firstVisibleItemPosition  = manager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
int lastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition  = manager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
int lastVisibleItemPositionPosition   = manager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
```

when ever an item position changed on the first recycler view you need to take one of above integers and move the second recycler view position accordingly, using LayoutManager

```
LinearLayoutManager secondListManagaer = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
secondListManagaer.scrollToPosition(above integer value. );
```

Hope this will get you started.